# New Interaction doesn't show after 2nd: using IdentifyAs

Tags: xconnect, tracking, contact

I am developing a function to support tracking user behavior through a mobile app.

Below is the current scenario:

***Case 1: Anonymous User 1 - Working fine:***

- Anonymous user visits the page, then these histories (interactions)
  are stored into xdb for anonymous user 1.
- When user logs in, Anonymous user 1 is loaded and assigned to the
  current session by ContactManager factory.
- After that, it will call     IdentifyAs() method Identifying to know
  contact: userlogin

  > (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("mysource",
  > > **userlogin** )
- **Result:** For this case, it is running as per our expectation: all interactions and every new interaction of anonymous user 1 will be shown on **userlogin**

***Case 2: Anonymous User 2/New Anonymous User - Not working fine:***

- A new anonymous user visits the page, then these histories (interactions) are stored into xdb for Anonymous user 2.
- When user logs in, Anonymous user 2 is loaded and assigned to the current session by ContactManager factory.
- After that, it will call IdentifyAs() method Identifying to know
  contact: **userlogin**

  > (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("mysource",
  > **userlogin** )
- **Result:** For this case, all interactions of anonymous user 2 are shown on **userlogin** but new interaction for Anonymous user 2 won't be shown on **userlogin**

*My expectation is every new interaction of anonymous user 1 will be shown on **userlogin** too.*

Any suggestion for case 2 ? (My expectation is every new interaction of anonymous user 2 will be shown on userlogin too.)

Comment: If I open an incognito chrome, visit page 1, then get identifiedAs("userLogin"), then visit page 2. In my xConnect for userLogin will be page1 and page2 on my contact. If I open a new incognito and visit page 3, then get identifiedAs("userLogin"), then visit page 4. On my xConnect for userLogin will be a 2nd visit with page3 and page4 on it. And one "merged" identifier in my list of identifiers.

Comment: @ChrisAuer nope, my situation is for Mobile app  I added new interaction for Mobile app via Sitecore Univeral Tracker

Comment: When you call identifyAs() sitecore will merge the Anonymous contact with the known one, in your case `userlogin`, but that might not happen right away, to know if the merge was triggered or not, look at the `MergeInfo` facet in the Anonymous contact, if you can find it = the merge happen, if you can't find it = the merge didn't happen yet https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/merge-contacts.html    Hope this helps